# Python: Iterating through a directory of text files, and processing the files into one CSV file.

Tags: python, csv, email

I am building a program that processes a large data-set of spam emails to find certain features out about the data.  For example, if there is a malicious word in it.  This would then be given as an output of 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' for each feature that is searched for.
All spam email files are .txt format within my directory.

I require it to iterate, reading each .txt file individually at a time and running the processing code through it, then outputting to the CSV file. Once each .txt file is completed, the next .txt file can be processed.
I need this action to be performed on all my .txt files and save the results all to one CSV file.

Is there a possible solution to this?
Thanks.

```
#Input:
file = open("C:\User\Documents\Dataset\Spam/*.txt", "r")
email = (file.read())

.
.
.
.
.
#code that processes features of the text file 
.
.
.
.
.

#Output:
with open('processedEmails.csv', 'w') as p:
    theWriter = csv.writer(p)
    theWriter.writerow(['Key Words', 'Address User By Name', 'IP Based Url', 'Email Domain Blacklist', 'Dots in URL', 'Location', 'URL on Blacklist', 'URL on Whitelist', 'Url Shortened', 'Url TTL', 'Capital Letters', 'Attachments Present'])
    theWriter.writerow([(str(malWords)), (str(greeting)), (str(ipurl)), (str(blacklist)), (str(dotCount)), (str(g[0])), (str(bList)), (str(wList)), (str(shortened)), (str(ttl)), (str(capital)), (str(attachments))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use os to get the files list, process each file and add the results to a buffer, then at the end, write the buffer to the csv file.

```
import os

txt_dir= 'C:\\User\\Documents\\Dataset\\Spam'

file_list = list(os.scandir(txt_dir))
txt_file_list = list(filter(lambda x: x.path.endswith('.txt'), file_list ))
csv_lines = ''

for f in txt_file_list:
    with open(f, 'r') as email:
        data = email.read()
        # process file here, add to csv_lines
        csv_lines = csv_lines + processFile(data)

#Output:
with open('processedEmails.csv', 'w') as p:
    theWriter = csv.writer(p)
    theWriter.writerow(['Key Words', 'Address User By Name', 'IP Based Url', 'Email Domain Blacklist', 'Dots in URL', 'Location', 'URL on Blacklist', 'URL on Whitelist', 'Url Shortened', 'Url TTL', 'Capital Letters', 'Attachments Present'])
    theWriter.writerow([(str(malWords)), (str(greeting)), (str(ipurl)), (str(blacklist)), (str(dotCount)), (str(g[0])), (str(bList)), (str(wList)), (str(shortened)), (str(ttl)), (str(capital)), (str(attachments))])
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Although it isn't looping through the txt files and only processing one text file and outputting it to the CSV file.